# Reference request for a resolution

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, reference-works

Let $S:=k[t_0,t_1,\dots,t_n]$ and $f\in S$ be an irreducible, homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Denote by $R:=S/(f)$. Recall that the Kähler differential of $R$ is the $R$-module $\Omega^1_{R/k}$ that is universal among all derivations on $R$. In our case here, a construction of such differential is given by the following

$\Omega^1_{R/k}=(\bigoplus_{i=1}^nR\cdot dt_i)/(\bar{df})$

where $df:=\sum_{i=1}^n f_{t_i}dt_i$ and $f_{t_i}:=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}$ is the formal partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $t_i$. If $k$ is a field, then $\Omega^1_{R/k}$ has a natural grading as a graded $k$-algebra, with each $dt_i$ of homogenous degree one. There is the following graded resolution I happened to encounter in a paper:

$0\rightarrow R(-d)\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n+1}R(-1)\rightarrow \Omega^1_{R/k}\rightarrow 0$

where the left-hand map is multiplication with $(f_{t_0}, f_{t_1}, \ldots ,f_{t_n})$ and right-hand map sends every homogeneous $n$-tuple $(p_0, p_1, \ldots ,p_n)$ to $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{p_i}dt_i$.

> **Question**: I believe this resolution is well known in homological algebra. Is there a name to it or a proper textbook reference that
> highlights this resolution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to look at *Koszul resolutions*.

Comment: For any $Y\subset X$, a closed embedding of varieties over $k$, if $Y$ is defined by an ideal (sheaf), one has an exact sequence $I/ l^2\to \Omega^1_X\otimes O_Y\to \Omega^1_Y\to 0$. Apply it in your case and use the fact that $f$ is irreducible to get injectivity on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Following comment by Mohan, I managed to figure out the origin of the resolution. So I am posting the answer elaborating his comment here in case anyone else is interested to know.

The resolution is a simpler presentation of the classical exact sequence relating $\Omega^1_{S/k}$ and $\Omega^1_{R/k}$ (or geometrically relating $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}/k}$ and $\Omega^1_{Spec\,R/k}$) as found in Hartshorne (see Ch. II, Proposition 8.4A). To be more precise we have the following commutative diagram in the category of graded $R$-modules
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    (f)/(f^2) @>\delta>> \Omega^1_{S/k}\otimes_SR @>>> \Omega^1_{R/k}@>>>0\\
    @V\wr VV @V\wr VV @V1_{\Omega^1_{R/k}}VV\\
    R(-d) @>>\varphi> \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n+1}R(-1) @>\psi>>\Omega^1_{R/k}@>>>0
\end{CD}

where the first and second vertical (graded) isomorphisms are given by the

$gf\mapsto g\,\,,\,\,(\sum_{i=0}^np_idt_i)\otimes g\mapsto (p_0g,p_1g,\dots,p_ng)$

respectively, while the map $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as stated in the original posting above. As $f$ is irreducible, the map $\delta$ is then injective. Thus the graded resolution is actually the simpler presentation of the classical (short) exact sequence.